# Conflicting answers on simiarly linear PDEs!$\;( u_{xxxx}+4u_{xy}=\tan{x} )$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

At [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200950/classification-of-a-pde)
the equation $$ u_{xxxx}+4u_{xy}=\tan{x} $$ is being answered as **nonlinear**.

But as far as i know, the linearity of a DE only depends on the (most) dependent variable. And in this case (and usually in PDEs) that would be the variable $u$. So i think it has to be **linear**.

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145476/comparing-a-linear-pde-to-a-nonlinear-pde) for example: $$xy \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} − e^{x−y} \frac{∂^2u}{∂x∂y} + \frac{∂u}{∂x} − 2xu = \cos(xy) $$

There is the $\cos(xy)$ term which causes the equation to be inhomogeneous, but it will still be linear nonetheless.

Am i missing here something?

Comment: The first equation is most definitely linear. The answer in the other post is wrong on that point.

Comment: @Lord Commander. Your remak is pertinent. $ u_{xxxx}+4u_{xy}=\tan{x} $ is linear.

Comment: @mattos @ JJacquelin thanks!